# C# Mono - Property Name

Tags: c#, reflection, mono, xamarin.ios

Using C# and MonoTouch/Mono

I need to get the name of the property like this:

```
public string BalanceOwing
{
    get { return the-name-of-the-property "BalanceOwing" }
}
```

Comment: What? We'll need more context to what you are doing.  What is `the-name-of-the-property` supposed to mean?  Are you saying you want to use reflection to get the value of a property by name?  On what object?  etc.

Comment: Where exactly are you having difficulties? It is not clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I.e. you want to get the name of the property where the current code is being executed. Right?!? I do think this is only possible with an Aspect Orientiated Programming (AOP) tool like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly create a [reusable method](http://blogs.clariusconsulting.net/kzu/a-really-simple-viewmodel-base-class-with-strongly-typed-inotifypropertychanged/) which will provide you with what you need.

```
        protected String GetPropertyName<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TProperty>> propertyExpresion)
        {
            var property = propertyExpresion.Body as MemberExpression;
            if (property == null || !(property.Member is PropertyInfo) ||
                !IsPropertyOfThis(property))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    "Expression must be of the form 'this.PropertyName'. Invalid expression '{0}'.",
                    propertyExpresion), "propertyExpression");
            }

            return property.Member.Name;
        }
```

To use you would pass in the name of the property...

```
String propertyName = GetPropertyName(() => this.BalanceOwing);
```

As mentioned by Marc, there are performance implications (nothing we have formally benchmarked or noted as of current) however this has suited our team well when making use of `INotifyPropertyChanged` behavior and creating a strongly typed presence across our Models/ViewModels.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest approach here is exactly what you have - a basic literal `"BalanceOwing"`.

There is no `infoof` operator. There *are* some interesting ways to do this inside the framework with either expression-trees ( `() => BalanceOwing` ) or analysis of the stack-frame (`MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod()`) but both have a performance impact. Frankly, the literal is simpler, more direct, faster, and as long as you unit test it - just as reliable.

You can also look at external tools, such as PostSharp (SharpCrafters), but again: it sounds overkill here.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to avoid reflection on the properties especially if you ever anticipate doing it more than once.

My general thinking is to use an Attribute on top of the property and then cache the result into a static instance somewhere:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class FooNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string PropertyName { get; private set; }

    public FooNameAttribute(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }
}
```